# Creating more relevant results from LDA topic modeling?

Tags: nltk, gensim, lda, topic-modeling, word-cloud

I am doing a project for my degree and I have an actual client from another college. They want me to do all this stuff with topic modeling to an sql file of paper abstracts he's given me. I have zero experience with topic modeling but I've been using Gensim and Nlkt in a Jupyter notebook for this.

What he want's right now is for me to generate 10 or more topics, record the top 10 most overall common words from the LDA's results, and then if they are very frequent in each topic, remove them from the resulting word cloud and if they are more variant, remove the words from just the topics where they are infrequent and keep them in the more relevant topics.

He also wants me to compare the frequency of each topic from the sql files of other years. And, he wants these topics to have a name generated smartly from the computer.

I have topic models per year and overall, but of course they do not appear exactly the same way in each year. My biggest concern is the first thing he wants with the removal process. Is any of this possible? I need help figuring out where to look as google is giving me not what I want as I am probably searching it wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Show some of the code you use so we can give you more useful tips. Also use `nlp` tag, the tags you used are kind of specific and not followed by many people so your question might be hard to find for the relevant users.

By the whole word-removal thing do you mean stop words too? Or did you already remove those? Stop words are very common words ("the", "it", "me" etc.) which often appear high in most frequent word lists but do not really have any meaning for finding topics.

First you remove the stop words to make the most common words list more useful.

Then, as he requested, you look which (more common) words are common in ALL the topics (I can imagine in case of abstracts this is stuff like hypothesis, research, paper, results etc., so stuff that is abstract-specific but not useful for determining topics within different abstracts and remove those. I can imagine for this kind of analysis as well as the initial LDA it makes sense to use all the data from all years to have a large amount of data for the model to recognize patterns. But you should try around the variations and see if the per year or overall versions get you nicer results.

After you have your global word lists per topic you go back to the original data (split up by year) to count the frequencies of how often the combined words from a topic occur per year. If you view this over the years you probably can see trends like some topics that are popular in the last few years/now but if you go back far enough they werent relevant.

The last thing you mentioned (automatically assigning labels to topics) is actually something quite tricky, depending on how you go about it.

The "easy" way would be e.g. just use the most frequent word in each topic as label but the results will probably be underwhelming.

A more advanced approach is Topic Labeling. Or you can try an approach like modified text summarization using more powerful models.